# Create Trigger to Print Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I am trying to create a trigger which print warning when assign the same course to the same teacher again.

But there are problem, if condition is true the trigger working correctly, but if condition is false the trigger not working and output errors through running, what's the problem?

This is my trigger:

create or replace TRIGGER CHECK_ASSIGN

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF teacher_id, course_id ON TEACHERS_COURSES

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

x teachers_courses %rowtype;

ex EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

select teacher_id, course_id into x from teachers_courses, courses, TEACHERS

```
where courses.C_id = TEACHERS_COURSES.Course_id

and TEACHERS.T_ID = TEACHERS_COURSES.TEACHER_ID
```

and teachers_courses.teacher_ID = :new.teacher_id

and teachers_courses.course_ID = :new.course_id;

if x.teacher_id = :new.teacher_id and x.course_id = :new.course_id then

```
raise ex;
```

else

```
  dbms_output.put_line('Inserting Success');
```

end if;

exception

when ex then

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'ERROR: You are assign same course to the same teacher.');
```

END;

I have three tables and they are:

```
COURSES: 
     course_id (PK) 
     course_name

TEACHERS: 
     teacher_id (PK) 
     teacher_name.

TEACHERS_COURSES 
      teacher with his courses
```

Answer (score 1):

dmbs_output cannot work when it is used in a trigger, because the process running the trigger cannot write to a terminal, because there is no terminal attached to the actual process running the query or code in the DB.

Use the UTL_FILE package to write to a file instead, or RAISE an error.